# How to deploy spring mvc application in jboss server?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jboss

I am implementing a Spring MVC application using JBoss application server.
I am getting the following exceptions when i run the application during JBoss server start up.
Where as it's working fine in Tomcat.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions.
I am using Eclipse IDE.

```
Unexpected error during load of:com.ibm.icu.impl.data.LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 60 in class file com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN

Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/virtual/VirtualFileVisitor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this post, I follow this and seems the exception not exist again
[Javassist failure in hibernate: invalid constant type: 60](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026956/javassist-failure-in-hibernate-invalid-constant-type-60)