# Java JPA Hibernate Connection Issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, java-8, persistence.xml

I'm using Netbeans to connect to a database. I want to use Java persistence to retrieve data from the database but I'm getting these errors:

```
jun 18, 2014 9:41:44 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
jun 18, 2014 9:41:44 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.6.Final}
jun 18, 2014 9:41:44 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
jun 18, 2014 9:41:44 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at controle_entregas.controleEntregasUI.jMenuItemNovaEntregaActionPerformed(controleEntregasUI.java:199)
    at controle_entregas.controleEntregasUI.access$100(controleEntregasUI.java:18)
    at controle_entregas.controleEntregasUI$2.actionPerformed(controleEntregasUI.java:85)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at controle_entregas.CadEditEntrega.<clinit>(CadEditEntrega.java:33)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading file:/C:/Users/Huberto/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Controle_Entregas/build/classes/
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addMetadataFromScan(Ejb3Configuration.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:363)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1113)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1056)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:150)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:765)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.checkAnnotationMatching(AbstractJarVisitor.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.executeJavaElementFilter(AbstractJarVisitor.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.addElement(AbstractJarVisitor.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.doProcessElements(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.getMatchingEntries(AbstractJarVisitor.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:128)
    ... 48 more
```

This is how I call it:

```
public class CadEditEntrega extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static DBConnect connection = null;
    private static final String tabela = "clientes";    
    private Integer id = null;
    private Date date = null;

    @PersistenceContext
    static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Controle_EntregasPU");
    public EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    /**
     * Creates new form CadEditEntrega
     * @param connection
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     * @throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
     */

    public CadEditEntrega(DBConnect connection) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        CadEditEntrega.connection = connection;
        this.date = new Date();
        initComponents();
        jDateChooser.setDate(date);
        preencheComboCliente();
        preencheComboProduto();
    }

    private void preencheComboCliente() throws SQLException{
        /*ResultSet result = connection.dbSelect("*", "clientes");
        while(result.next()){
            jComboBoxCliente.addItem(result.getString("cliente_nome"));
        }*/
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        List<Clientes> list = em.createNamedQuery("Clientes.findAll", Clientes.class).getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }
}
```

And this is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Controle_EntregasPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>controle_entregas.Clientes</class>
    <class>controle_entregas.Movimentacao</class>
    <class>controle_entregas.MovimentacaoProdutos</class>
    <class>controle_entregas.Produtos</class>
    <class>controle_entregas.TiposMovimentacao</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://mysql22.******:3306/******?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="******"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuAYl.png

Comment: Hard to say, but `Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18` may point to a damaged file. Check if the jars are really .jar and class files really .class.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026956/javassist-failure-in-hibernate-invalid-constant-type-60

Comment: Try also to set project to source/binary/platform to JDK1.7.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Java 8? If you are you might want to use the latest Javassist. At least I found when I was using version of 3.12 GA of Javassist I had this problem. So in your Maven POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried that but I am still facing the following exception:  java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18

Answer (score 0):

following on Fly answer, like he said, this seems to be related to java 8.
Actually hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-core both bring their own versions of javassist.

I assume you're using maven, so you can actually see it in the command line with:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Even easier, in case you use Eclipse is the tab `Dependency Hierarchy` tab when viewing the pom.xml.

You'll need to see where these dependencies are being brought from and exclude them as such:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

After this you can add the dependency as Fly indicated and all should work.

Tested with 3.18.1-GA by the way.